# Map http request respond json data to Angular2 object and access from outside

Tags: javascript, json, http, angular, typescript

```
export class PersonEditDetailsComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {


person: Person;
sub: any;

constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let id = Number.parseInt(params['id']);
        console.log('getting person with id: ', id);
        this.peopleService
            .get(id) // send http request 
            .subscribe(response => this.person = response); // get response value
    });
}

//I want to access this.person values here.
}
```

I'm newbie to Angular2 JS. As above code, I just want to map the json response data to angular2 typescript object. How can I do this. It is getting 'response' value. But can not map to person object. I want to use response data from the outside

Comment: Can you share your JSON response here !

Comment: **access it from outside** what do you mean by outside?

Comment: Outside of the scope of ngOnInit() method

Answer (score 0):

`.subscribe(response => this.person = .json().data as Person); // get response value`

In you `PeopleService` on your `get` use `.publishLast().refCount()` to cache the result/

Comment: I want to map json data to person object and use it from outside

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your response, e.g in a method in your component, the easiest way would be to call that method from inside the subscription, after you have got your value to `person`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        let id = Number.parseInt(params['id']);
        console.log('getting person with id: ', id);
        this.peopleService
            .get(id)
            .subscribe(response =>  {
               this.person = response;
               this.doSomething(); // call method here!
            });
    });
}

doSomething() {
  console.log(this.person) // here value is available!
}
```

Comment: Did either answer help you? :)